# rsync running at the same time on two machines

Tags: rsync

I would like to set up rsync to run on two machines.

```
Machine A rsync to Machine B
Machine B rsync to Machine A
```

Would there be any risk of running rsync in two machines at the same time, synching the same files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're *very* careful you can do it:

1. Ensure that you use `--times` so that the time stamps always match, and `--update` so that it will not overwrite newer versions.
2. Use `--temp-dir` with a directory outside the synced tree so that rsync does not find any temp files during its scan. The temporary directory should be on the same file-system as the destination, however, or else atomic moves won't be possible.
3. Do *not* use `--inplace`, any variant of `--delete`, or `--checksum`.

Even then, I would always do it first one way, and then the other, or use a tool like SyncThing.